# $f(x)=\sin x^3$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Question is to prove that :

$f(x)=\sin x^3$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous.

What would my first observation in checking uniform continuity is to check if its derivative is bounded.

In this case its derivative $f'(x)=3x^2\sin x^3$ which is unbounded. So, I can not rely on this.

I tried with definition :

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sin x^3-\sin y^3|=|2\cos (\frac{x^3+y^3}{2})\sin (\frac{x^3-y^3}{2})|\leq 2 |\sin (\frac{x^3-y^3}{2})|$

I see that $\sin x \leq  x$.. This may not imply $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ but  i am assuming it...

So, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2 |\sin (\frac{x^3-y^3}{2})|\leq 2\frac{|x^3-y^3|}{2}=|x^3-y^3|=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|$.

Though $|x-y|$ is small i should make $|f(x)-f(y)|$ considerably large.

I now have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2 |x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|$

I some how can sense that I can make $|x^2+xy+y^2|$ large enough though $|x-y|$ is small but not so sure how to make this in $\epsilon-\delta$ case.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

EDIT : I know that uniform continuous functions takes cauchy sequence to cauchy sequence and tried to use it in this case. But, I could not find correct cauchy sequence that would help me to go through this.

I would be thankful if some one can help me in this way too.

Comment: "In this case its derivative $f'(x)=3x^2\sin x^3$ which is unbounded."

Comment: Yes Yes but i am not so sure how to use this negative result.. I am familiar with how to use positive result i.e., derivative is bounded but not this.... :(

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ has an unbounded derivative. Yet it's uniformly continuous. You cannot use the negative result in general.

Comment: @AymanHourieh : Yes Yes that is what i have in mind.. I can not use negative result...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $x_n=(n\pi+\pi/2)^{1/3}$, then $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$ but $f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)=\pm2$ hence $f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)$ does not converge to $0$. Therefore, no uniform continuity.

Comment: But, I am confused how could one get such idea just from nothing :(

Comment: Yes this funtion does not preserve cauchy sequences therefore is not uniformly continuous. The general idea is to select a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ and prove that $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence. For example the sequence on the (Did) comment.

Comment: From nothing? Well, I would not say that... One tries to have nonvanishing differences $f(x)-f(y)$, obviously this comes from the fact that $f$ is defined on the whole real line, not a bounded interval, the maximal amplitude is when the sine is $\pm1$, hence...

Comment: @Did : Yes yes.. just now i could realize something... Thank you thank you...... may be i need some time... Thanks again...

Comment: @Did How to find out that this sequence tends to zero... If it was square,it's easy but what to do for cube.